# Eisenbud's picture of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-3)$

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

Does anyone know how to remake the picture of  $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-3)$ as found in "The Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris? The picture is the following and it is found in section II.4 on page 86:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. I think that your drawing is done with Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape for example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need some lines, and curves, and dots and a few nodes/labels/pins. The [`radial` shading](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/shading) should helb with those blurry balls.

Comment: I have the feeling that I saw something similar on this site ... Maybe try to come up with something first, then it is easier to help you. the curvy lines in the center can be created using `to[out=90, in=135]` or something similar.

Comment: @Sebastiano The font in the labels seems to be Computer Modern though. So maybe it was created with TeX. But we will never know probably.

Comment: Have you contacted Eisenbud or Harris? They might send you whatever computer files they used.

Comment: Hi everyone, the reason I asked this question is that I saw someone recreate the original Mumford picture of Spec Z[x] in this post: https://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/2011/05/25/a-latex-version-of-mumfords-impression-of-spec-zx-or-some-tikz-tricks/ , but I do not know how to tweak it to get one that looks like the Eisenbud one above

Comment: @JasperHabicht Also with AI it is possible to create a graph with a font CM.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, you are totally right! I was just thinking that this *could* be a hint that it had maybe been produced using Ti*k*Z. Only the authors know it for sure, I guess ... =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They probably did not use `pin`s, but this might be close enough:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={
        node contents={},
        circle,
        fill,
        inner sep=1pt,
    },
    big dot/.style={
        node contents={},
        circle,
        fill=gray,
        inner sep=2.5pt,
    },
    fuzzy/.style={
        node contents={},
        circle,
        inner color=black,
        outer color=white,
        inner sep=6pt,
    },
    every label/.style={
        inner sep=1pt,
    },
    every pin/.style={
        pin edge={thin, black, shorten <=3pt},
        pin distance=1cm,
        anchor=north,
        inner sep=1pt,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]

    \draw[thick] (1,0) -- (15,0) node[fuzzy, label={below right:{(0)}}];
    \foreach \x in {2,3,5,7,11,13} {
        \path (\x,0) node[dot, label={below:{(\x)}}];

        \ifnum\x<12\relax
            \draw[thick] (\x,1) -- ++(0,2) 
                \ifnum\x=2\relax
                    node[fuzzy, label={above left:{(\x)}}];
                \else
                    node[fuzzy, label={above right:{(\x)}}];
                \fi
        \fi
    }

    \draw[thick] (15,1) -- ++(0,2) 
        node[fuzzy, inner sep=9pt, label={above right:{(0)}}];

    \draw[thick] 
        (2,1.75) 
        to[out=270, in=270, distance=15pt] 
        (3,1.75) 
        to[out=270, in=180, distance=25pt] 
        (5,1.75) 
        to[out=0, in=180] (6,1.375) to[out=0, in=180]
        (7,1.75)
        to[out=0, in=180] (11,1.375) 
        node[dot, pin={330:{$(11, x+5)$}}] 
        to
        (13,1.375) node[dot]
        to[out=0, in=180]
        (15,1.75);
    
    \draw[thick] 
        (2,1.75) node[dot, pin={240:{$(2, x-1)$}}]
        to[out=90, in=90, distance=15pt] 
        (3,1.75) node[dot, pin={300:{$(3, x)$}}]
        to[out=90, in=180, distance=25pt] 
        (5,1.75) node[big dot, pin={300:{$(5, x^2-3)$}}]
        to[out=0, in=180] (6,2.125) to[out=0, in=180]
        (7,1.75) node[big dot]
        to[out=0, in=180] (11,2.175) 
        node[dot, pin={30:{$(11, x-5)$}}]
        to
        (13,2.175) node[dot]
        to[out=0, in=180]
        (15,1.75)
        node[fuzzy, pin={240:{$(x^2-3)$}}];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]